# Download Image from google drive Android API?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I successfully integrated google drive in my android app. But could not download selected image file. 
Here is my code. There is a problem Result call back method is never execute. Kindly help me. And also I used **data.getData()** method in **onActivity** result this method only **return null**. How I can find URI of image?

```
package com.example.syedfurqan.dropboxintegration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dropbox.chooser.android.DbxChooser;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveResource;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Metadata;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityBuilder;

import java.io.InputStream;



public class BaseDemoActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "BaseDriveActivity";

    protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;

    private static final int REQ_CODE_OPEN = 2;


    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_demo);
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) 
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_OPEN:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    DriveId mFileId = (DriveId) data
                            .getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                    DriveFile selectedFile = mFileId.asDriveFile();


                    selectedFile.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                            .setResultCallback(idCallback);

                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }


//Picker
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
        // Launch user interface and allow user to select file
        try {
            IntentSender i = Drive.DriveApi
                    .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                    .setMimeType(new String[]{"image/png", "image/jpeg"})
                    .build(mGoogleApiClient);
            startIntentSenderForResult(i, REQ_CODE_OPEN, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                // Handle an error
            }
            DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
            InputStream is = driveContents.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            Values.setBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    };



    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            // show the localized error dialog.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Shows a toast message.
     */

    public void showMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    /**
     * Getter for the {@code GoogleApiClient}.
     */

    public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
        return mGoogleApiClient;
    }


}
```

Comment: I found the solution now.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just used Android Google Drive default API classes for doing my task. And here is code:

//BaseDemoActivity

```
package com.example.syedfurqan.dropboxintegration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;

public abstract class BaseDemoActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "BaseDriveActivity";
    protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;


    /**
     * Google API client.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    /**
     * Handles resolution callbacks.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is connected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is disconnected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is trying to connect but failed.
     * Handle {@code result.getResolution()} if there is a resolution is
     * available.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            // show the localized error dialog.
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows a toast message.
     */
    public void showMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the {@code GoogleApiClient}.
     */
    public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
        return mGoogleApiClient;
    }
}
```

//Retrieve Content

```
package com.example.syedfurqan.dropboxintegration;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile.DownloadProgressListener;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityBuilder;

import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * An activity to illustrate how to open contents and listen
 * the download progress if the file is not already sync'ed.
 */
public class RetreiveContent extends BaseDemoActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "RetrieveFileWithProgressDialogActivity";

    /**
     * Request code to handle the result from file opening activity.
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = 1;

    /**
     * Progress bar to show the current download progress of the file.
     */
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    /**
     * File that is selected with the open file activity.
     */
    private DriveId mSelectedFileDriveId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBar.setMax(100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        super.onConnected(connectionHint);

        // If there is a selected file, open its contents.
        if (mSelectedFileDriveId != null) {
            open();
            return;
        }

        // Let the user pick an mp4 or a jpeg file if there are
        // no files selected by the user.
        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                .setMimeType(new String[]{"video/mp4", "image/png", "image/jpeg"})
                .build(getGoogleApiClient());
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
//            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_OPENER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mSelectedFileDriveId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
                    OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);

//            open();
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    private void open() {
        // Reset progress dialog back to zero as we're
        // initiating an opening request.
        mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        DownloadProgressListener listener = new DownloadProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(long bytesDownloaded, long bytesExpected) {
                // Update progress dialog with the latest progress.
                int progress = (int) (bytesDownloaded * 100 / bytesExpected);
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Loading progress: %d percent", progress));
                mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        };
        Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(), mSelectedFileDriveId)
                .open(getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, listener)
                .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
        mSelectedFileDriveId = null;
    }

    private ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
            new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        showMessage("Error while opening the file contents");
                        return;
                    }
                    DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
                    InputStream is = driveContents.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    Values.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    //showMessage("File contents opened");
                    RetreiveContent.this.finish();

                }
            };
}
```

Comment: So great!. Thanks.